# Calculating the area of cylinder whose radius varies linearly as a function of height using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the volume shown below, I would like to determine the shaded area (area of the circle) which varies linearly as a function of the height $l$ of the object between radius $a$ and radius $b$. I can obtain the expression using basic geometry but I wondered if I could do this using a surface integral?

The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ and using the formula for a straight line I obtain the expression for the area of the circle as $$\pi(a+\frac{b-a}{l}z)^2$$

I want to get this expression using calculus. I note that the unit vector normal to the surface is in the $\hat{Z}$ direction and therefore I pick $dS = rdrd\phi$

The surface integral for the area is $$A = \int_{s} ds = \int_{a}^{b} rdr \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi $$

The result of which is

$$A = \pi(b^2 - a^2)$$

This however doesn't take into account the height of the volume. What did I do incorrectly? 
[image: Cylindrical volume with radius which varies linearly with height]

Comment: This shape is often called a *truncated cone* or *frustum*

Comment: At least one point is that your integration does not contain any reference to the height $z$ you are considering. In addition, why would you have an integral from $a$ to $b$? I'm not familiar with the formula you are using, could it be that it is for the surface of the object, which you are not interested in? Also, the unit normal to the surface is absolutely not in the $Z$-direction.

Comment: @ingrix it is the formula for the surface of the object. I'd like to obtain the surface area of just the shaded circle whose radius will vary with height. As far as i can tell the unit normal to that circular face is in Z-direction as defined by the co-ordinate system given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits for $r$ are $a$ to $b$.  Instead they should be $0$ to $(a+(b-a)z/l)$.